# How do I convert an NSMutableString to NSString when using Frameworks?

Tags: objective-c, frameworks, nsstring, nsmutablestring

I have written an Objective-C framework which builds some HTML code with NSMutableString which returns the value as an NSString.

I have declared an NSString and NSMutableString in the inteface .h file:

```
NSString *_outputLanguage;        // Tests language output
NSMutableString *outputBuilder;
NSString *output;
```

This is a sample from the framework implementation .m code (I cannot print the actual code as it is proprietary):

```
-(NSString*)doThis:(NSString*)aString num:(int)aNumber {
if ([outputBuilder length] != 0) {
    [outputBuilder setString:@""];
}
if ([_outputLanguage isEqualToString:@"html"]) {
    [outputBuilder appendString:@"Some Text..."];
    [outputBuilder appendString:aString];
    [outputBuilder appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", aNumber]];
}
else if ([_outputLanguage isEqualToString:@"xml"]) {
    [outputBuilder appendString:@"Etc..."];
}
else {
    [outputBuilder appendString:@""];
}
output = outputBuilder;
return output;
}
```

When I wrote a text program, NSLog simply printed out "(null)". The code I wrote there was:

```
TheClass *instance = [[TheClass alloc] init];
NSString *testString = [instance doThis:@"This String" num:20];
NSLog(@"%@", testString);
[instance release];
```

I hope this is enough information!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing that you're forgetting to `alloc/init` your strings...

Comment: To give an example: have you at any point in your .m file got a line like this:

    `outputBuilder = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];`

If not, you need it.

Comment: Thanks! I forgot to alloc/init - I've added a custom init method to take care of this.

Answer (score 0):

Your `doThis:` method doesn't seem to initialise `outputBuilder`.  So if it is a null pointer, then nothing will be done to it.

Comment: Uh... `doThis:` is an instance method, and it's being invoked on `instance`, so it would seem that `instance` was indeed initialized...  I don't really get what you're saying.

Comment: maybe he meant `outputBuilder`?

Comment: Thanks! I've added a new init method to take care of allocating and initialising.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `outputBuilder` is valid. Where are you `alloc/init`'ing it?

Comment: Thanks! I forgot to actually alloc/init! I have created a new init method to take care of this.